# Multithreading, Multiprocessing with STOP and Continue Signals

Tags: java, multithreading, signals, ptrace

I am working on a project where I need to get the native stack of the Java application. I am able to achieve this partially thanks to ptrace, multiprocessing, and signals.

On Linux, a normal Java application has, at a minimum, 14 threads. Out of these 14, I am interested in only the main thread of which I have to get the native stack. Considering this objective, I have started a separate process using `fork()` which is monitoring the native stack of the main thread. In short, I have 2 separate processes: one is being monitored and the other does the monitoring using ptrace and signal handling.

Steps in the monitoring process:

1. Get the main thread ID out of the 14 threads from the monitored process.
2. `ptrace_attach` on the main ID.
3. `ptrace_cont` on the main ID.

**continuous loop starts**

**{**

4. `kill(main_ID, SIGSTOP)`
5. `nanosleep` and check the status from the `/proc/[pid]/stat` directory.
6. `ptrace_peekdata` to read the stack and navigate.
7. `ptrace_cont` on the main ID.
8. `nanosleep` and check the status from the `/proc/[pid]/stat` directory.

**}**

9. `ptrace_detach` on the main ID.

This perfectly gives the native stack information continuously. However, sometimes I encounter an issue:

When I `kill(main_ID, SIGSTOP)` the main thread, the other threads from the process get into a finished or stoped state (T) and the entire process blocks. This is not the consistent behavior and sometimes entire process executes correctly. I cannot understand this behavior as i am only signaling the main thread. Why are the other threads affected?

Can someone help me analyze this problem?

I also tried sending `SIGCONT` and `SIGSTOP` to all of the threads of the process but the issue still occurs sometimes.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: as per my understanding so far..

Comment: there is a Default signal handler corresponding to the Signal on the Process Level. when the process finds Signal for any of its Child Threads, The respective Signal is being handled by any one of the thread depending upon the status i.e. busy or free. this could be the reason for the inconsistent results for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Linux, you should be using tkill(2) or tgkill(2) instead of kill(2). On FreeBSD, you should use the SYS_thr_kill2 syscall. Per the tkill(2) manpage:

> tgkill()  sends  the signal sig to the thread with the thread ID tid in
>   the thread group tgid.  (By contrast, kill(2) can only be used to  send
>   a signal  to a process (i.e., thread group) as a whole, and the signal
>   will be delivered to an arbitrary thread within that process.)

Ignore the stuff about tkill(2) and friends being for internal thread library usage, it is commonly used by debuggers/tracers to send signals to specific threads.

Also, you should use waitpid(2) (or some variation of it) to wait for the thread to receive the SIGSTOP instead of polling on /proc/[pid]/stat. This approach will be more efficient and more responsive.

Finally, it appears that you are doing some sort of stack sampling. You may want to check out [Google PerfTools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/) as these tools include a CPU sampler that is doing stack sampling to obtain estimates of what functions are consuming the most CPU time. You could maybe reuse the work these tools have already done, as stack sampling can be tricky to make robust.